# ¿Como hago para agregar datos a un datastore de google cloud en python y django?

Tags: python, django, postman, gcloud, google-datastore

Eso pues, estoy haciendo un metodo POST para agregar datos por una app y colocarlas en un datastore de google cloud, pero cuando ejecuto la funcion, estos datos no se guardan.

Aca esta el codigo de views.py:

```
import json
import csv

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from tracking.serializers import ActuatorSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseServerError, HttpResponse, response
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.views import View
from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data as xlsx_get
from .serializers import ActuatorSerializer, MeasureMagnitudeSerializer
from .serializers import SensorSerializer, StationSerializer
from .models import Actuator, MeasureMagnitude, Sensor, Station
from .utils.datastore import DatastoreConnector
from datetime import datetime

class DatastoreAPI(View):
    @csrf_exempt
    def save(request):
        print(request.body) #Aca muestro en consola los datos recuperados del postman
        JSON = json.loads(request.body)
        print(JSON)
        dataStoreConnector = DatastoreConnector()
        res = dataStoreConnector.post(JSON)
        return JsonResponse({'msg' : f"Se subieron los registros."})
```

Aqui esta el datastore.py:

```
import time
import traceback
import sys
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from google.cloud import datastore
from ..models import Sensor, Station

class DatastoreConnector:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.datastoreClient = datastore.Client()
        pass
    #metodo write que acepte JSON
    def post(self, data):
        print("1-------------------------")
        entity = datastore.Entity(
                key=self.datastoreClient.key('aquamype_sensordata'))
        print(entity)
        print("2-------------------------")
        entity.update(
            data
        )
        print(entity)
        print("3-------------------------")
        self.datastoreClient.put(entity)
        print(entity)
        print("4-------------------------")
```

Es porque cuando hago el metodo POST, estoy llamando estos metodos desde la urls.py.
En el postman, pongo estos datos:

```
{ 
  "latitude": 0, 
  "longitude": 0, 
  "sensors": {}, 
  "station_id": 0, 
  "object_id": 0,
  "timestamp": 0
}
```

Y me devuelve esto:

```
{"msg": "Se subieron los registros."}
```

Pero cuando voy al datastore de gcloud no aparecen los datos nuevos